# errors seen when selecting Sun Java 6

Tags: java, linux, jvm, xulrunner

On Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick), I have both `java-6-openjkd` and `java-6-sun` as shown with the `update-java-alternatives -l` command.

However when I set the alternative to Sun, via the command

`sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun`

I see the following:

```
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
update-alternatives: error: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so for mozilla-javaplugin.so not registered, not setting.
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

Does this result in `xulrunner` being non-functional or simply result in it continuing to use the Open JVM?  Likewise I am posing the similar question in regard to `mozilla-javaplugin.so`.

**Update** Switching back to OpenJDK also results in an error:

```
$ sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-openjdk

update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for xulrunner-1.9-javaplugin.so.
```

What if anything can be done about this?

**Update** I am swayed by this [commentary on why instructions were written to install Sun Java](https://launchpad.net/~flexiondotorg/+archive/java) that it will be less risky human attention/time-wise to use Sun.  I am using and also API interfacing to an Web Start application where the support materials all refer to Sun.

Answer (score 1):

> Sun-6-java is being phased out by Oracle and is no longer supported. This is why there are no plugins available for your browser anymore.
>
> OpenJDK is the only stack you should be using as sun-java-6 is outdated and deprecated.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenJDK
>
> If you would like to use Proprietary Closed Source features in Java you will need to >install the version from java.com (which is also OpenJDK so don't really see any benefit >over the Ubuntu Repository version).
>
> OpenJDK is backwards compatible with the old Sun-6-java. What can you not run with OpenJDK?

Quoted from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79747/update-alternatives-error-no-alternatives-for).

Comment: I am interfacing to an API that has documentation referring to Sun for Windows clients.  Although I am not on Windows, there is no equivalent documentation for Linux so I am inferring that there might be fewer compatibility problems with Sun.  That said, it might work either way.

Comment: I hope it works out for you.  Sorry I couldn't provide more information, but I feel that search should help.

Comment: @broiyan - it is extremely likely that something that works on the Sun proprietary JVM will work on a OpenJDK JVM at the same version / patch number.  The Sun flavor is basically the OpenJDK with some "secret sauce" at the JVM level.

Comment: If you're still having problems then that suggests that your plugins are not installed correctly.

Comment: As of 2012 January 22, Java 6 does not appear to be deprecated.  If you browse (using an Ubuntu computer) to java.com the main download page is for Java 6 Update 30.  On the sidebar you can get Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoted from the same place](https://askubuntu.com/a/94052) of @Aeterna

> Actually you can simply add the partner repository in
> /etc/apt/sources.list :
>
> deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
>
> If you are not
> on lucid, replace lucid with your distribution (you can get it with
> lsb_release -c).
>
> If you still have problem with the java plugin, you can do like I did,
> [follow the instructions here](http://www.php-architect.com/blog/2010/10/19/installing-java-plugin-for-firefox-on-ubuntu-10-10-maverick/) :
>
> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/mozilla-javaplugin.so mozilla-java
>
> If you are not on a 64 bits system, replace amd64 by i386.